# Distorted vlc playback with x264 encoded file

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, capture, vlc, x264

I have captured raw video in rgb format from my webcam using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 -f rawvideo \
-pix-fmt rgb24 -r10 webcam.rgb24
```

This raw video file plays ok in mplayer.

I encode this file using x264:

```
x264 --input-res 320x240 --demuxer raw --input-fmt rgb24 --fps 10 \
-o webcam.mkv webcam.rgb24
```

However when I try to play webcam.mkv with vlc it is an interlaced, distorted image.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you also using ffmpeg for the conversion?  Certainly less chance of incompatibility surrounding somewhat esoteric formats that way.

Comment: I am evaluating x264 for use in a project.  The work with ffmpeg and mplayer is simply to generate and verify test data.

Answer (score 1):

After some further research I was able to successfully encode the raw video stream.  The problem (I think) was that x264 expects yuv420p formatted data.  When I changed the capture format I could play the mkv file without any distortion.

Capture command:

```
ffmpeg -t 10 -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 -f rawvideo \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 10 webcam.yuv420p
```

(capture from input device /dev/video0 for 10 secs at a frame rate of 10 and output to file webcam.yuv420p in yuv420p pixel format)

Encode command:

```
x264 --input-res 320x240 --demuxer raw  --input-fmt yuv420p --fps 10 \
-o webcam.mkv webcam.yuv420p
```

Play command:

```
mplayer -vo gl:nomanyfmts webcam.mkv
```

(Or open with vlc)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you use --input-fmt option (which exists specifically for lavf demuxer) with --demuxer raw. With raw demuxer you should use --input-csp option (with bgr value probably for ffmpeg's -pix-fmt rgb24).